# gitbook editor missing content of file only show file

Tags: gitbook

I downloaded gitbook editor. It is not the online version. Since I want to use the legacy version of gitbook editor, I downloaded it. When you open the gitbook editor usually has content of file and file. But for me, the content of the file is completely missing only has file column. I tried to reinstall gitbook editor. But the still persists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved. i go to gitbook editor to change the summary file
since i rename the readme file to empty. in gitbook file you can still see readme 
but in summary readme become its new name empty.. usually readme is called introduction on table of content automatically.. so you can rename introduction but never rename it as empty